# jupyter notebook does not start

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter

I am trying to use Jupyter Notebook but somehow when I open it tells me that the kernel died and can not start.
I have this error:

```
/Users/mas/anaconda3/bin/python: No module named bash_kernel
```

What do you think the problem can be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `pip install bash_kernel`

Link: `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bash_kernel`